# How to rename all the files and no overwriting?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file-rename

I know how to rename all the files in the folder with numbers:

```
i=1
for f in *.jpg
do
    NEW_NAME=$( printf "%05d.jpg" $i )
#   echo mv "$f" "$( printf "%05d.jpg" $i )"
    mv -n "$f" "$NEW_NAME"
    ((i++))
done
```

So all my files will be renames, but if I have a file like `0004.jpg`, it will not rename the file as n+1. I have tried to add a loop for increasing `i` if the name exists:

```
i=1
for f in *.jpg
do
    NEW_NAME=$( printf "%05d.jpg" $i )
#   echo mv "$f" "$( printf "%05d.jpg" $i )"
    mv -n "$f" "$NEW_NAME"
    MV=$?
    while [ $MV -ne 0 ]
    do
        ((i++))
        NEW_NAME=$( printf "%05d.jpg" $i )
        mv -n "$f" "$NEW_NAME"
        MV=$?       
    done
    ((i++))
done
```

but it seems not to work. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `mv -n` returns zero even when the file already exists.

I'd be tempted to do this:

```
i=1
mkdir .newnames
for f in *.jpg
do
    NEW_NAME=$( printf "%05d.jpg" $i )
#   echo mv "$f" "$( printf "%05d.jpg" $i )"
    mv "$f" ".newnames/$NEW_NAME"
    ((i++))
done
mv .newnames/* .
rmdir .newnames
```

Basically, by moving the files into a temporary directory (the leading `.` (dot) prevents the for loop trying to rename it) you remove the potential for filename clashes.

Comment: Interesting approach! Thanks for the explanation

Comment: bash `printf` has a -v flag [for doing assignments](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf). It's a nonstandard feature of printf, but you can do `printf -v NEW_NAME '%05d.jpg' "$i"` to avoid the subshell.